# remove_widget kivy do not remove by name

Tags: kivy

I have this code, and I can’t remove the widget when I use the name of this widget: MainApp(). m.remove_widget (Butt()).

I understand that I am accessing this widget incorrectly, but I do not understand how to do it correctly.
Tell me how to remove a widget using its name?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.colorpicker import ColorPicker
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Butt(Button):
    def add_wid1(self):
        MainApp.m.add_widget(Box())
        MainApp.m.add_widget(Butt1())


class Butt1(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        print('111')
        MainApp().m.remove_widget(MainApp().m.children[1])    #this code works
        MainApp().m.remove_widget(Butt())    #this code not working


class Box (ColorPicker):
    size_hint=.50, .25


class Pict (Widget):
    pass


class MainApp (App):
    m = FloatLayout()
    def build (self):
        pic = Pict()
        MainApp.m.add_widget(pic)
        MainApp.m.add_widget(Butt())
        return MainApp.m

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: `MainApp().m.remove_widget(Butt())` tries to remove the instance of the `Butt` class (`Butt()`) that you create while calling it...

Comment: `remove_widget` takes as an argument a single widget that is currently a child of the widget whose method is being called. When you write `Butt()`, you create a *new* instance of the widget, which clearly isn't currently a child of the Butt1.

Comment: @inclement ok, how do I turn to the widget `Butt1()` from `MainApp.m`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the instance of the `Butt` that you want to remove. An easy way to do it is to save a reference to that `Butt` in your `build` method:

```
self.butt = Butt()
MainApp.m.add_widget(self.butt)
```

and then remove it with:

```
app = App.get_running_app()
MainApp.m.remove_widget(app.butt)
```